# Can the FireComplex particle be activated on trigger only?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using the FireComplex particle to generate an explosion (a bomb) when the user presses spacebar. The fire is playing on awake which I don't want and it doesn't seem to include an option to disable it.

Can this be coded to only activate the fire particle when I press space? I have tried the following:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CombatController : MonoBehaviour {

    //public GameObject enemy;
    [SerializeField]
    public GameObject Bomb;
    public GameObject Fire;

if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space)) {
                BombExplosion ();
            }

        public void BombExplosion () {

            //Create the Bombs Explosion Particle Effect.
            Instantiate (Fire, this.gameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);  
            Fire.Emit(5); //Burn for 5 seconds
```

}

Unity seems to be ignoring the Fire.Emit function.

Comment: What is the `Fire` Type? Also, you can't access an instantiated object unless you make an instance of it.

Comment: The FireComplex prefab from standard assets

Comment: I can see you've edited your question. You mentioned that you don't want your particle to play on awake? Isn't there an option to disable this as one of the many properties of the Particle System in the inspector?

Comment: Oddly no, on some of the other particles it has this option but not on this fire.

Comment: It seems you're looking to actually instantiate the `Fire`, but you want to delay it?

Comment: It should only instantiate on keypress(spacebar). So press space to load the BombExplosion() function which will activate the fire effect.

Comment: Am I missing something here? It seems to me your code is already doing just that. Are you not seeing the instantiated particle?

Comment: The particle executes as soon as I start the game. I want the particle to only execute when I press space bar.

Answer (score 0):

The reason, I think, why the Bomb goes off after executing the game is because of the onviously incorrect logic in `GetKeyUp`. I doubt that it what you need.
Change it to `GetKey` instead.

Hope that clarifies the issue.

Comment: No, no the GetKeyUp logic is working fine. There is something else I need to do.